# Sql Developer uninstall on Mac

Tags: oracle, macos, oracle-sqldeveloper, uninstallation

I have Sql Developer installed in my MacBook Pro, 64-bit. I am trying to manually uninstall all of Sql developer components, but I need help locating those components on my computer. If there isn't a better way to uninstall, could you please help me locate those components?

Thank you

Answer (score 10):

1. **Just find the directory in Finder and remove it**. We don't have an installer or uninstaller.

[image]

2. **Then in  your $USER directory, remove the .sqldeveloper folder** - that will remove all of the application data files for your OS X account - things like SQL History, table filters, reports, etc.

   ┌─[09:07:01]─[wvu1999]─[MacBook-Air-Smith]:~$
   └─>ls -al 
   total 896
   drwxr-xr-x+  49 wvu1999  staff    1666 Jun  8 07:22 .
   drwxr-xr-x    8 root     admin     272 Nov  6  2014 ..
   drwxr-xr-x+  25 wvu1999  staff     850 Jun 12 15:27 .sqldeveloper
   drwxr-xr-x+   6 wvu1999  staff     204 Dec 10  2014 .subversion